# Unscope default scope on assciation without N+1 query in Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, eager-loading, default-scope

Let's say I have the following moduls:

`Category` has_many :products
`Product` has_many :tags
`Tag` has_one :author
`Author` has default scope

```
default_scope { where(active: true) }
```

Now when showing categories, I want to show also all products and tags within the product, but I also want to include tags from inactive users.

The most straightforward solution is to remove default scope and create explicit scope instead and use it on all places. But issue is there is a bunch of places where I would need to add that, so that solution is not viable.

The other option is to add new scope to `Product`

```
def all_tags
  Tag.joins(:author).unscope(author: { where: :active }).where(product_id: id)
end
```

This works, but it can lead to N+1 issue
If there are 10 products within each company with 5 tags in average per product, it would run 50 queries to DB and that's not what I want.

Is there any elegant way to solve N+1 issue?

Of course, I could lead all relevant tags in a controller, something like

```
@tags_per_product = Tag.joins(:author).unscope(author: { where: :active }).where(product_id: product_ids).group_by(&:product_id)
```

and then reuse `tags_per_product` in a view, but that looks a bit dirty

In Rails, it's always important to find neat and elegant way, so I would like to have it here

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not something as simple as `scope :all_tags, -> { tags.unscope(where: :archived)}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just edited the question. Tag has_one :user and user can be active/inactive. Instead of showing archived tags I want to show tags of inactive users

Comment: Also, I just tried this and got : undefined local variable or method tags, when I reference then in scope :all_tags

Comment: Sorry I was under the impress the product was tagged.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for delay. I wrote a solution in new post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this

In tag.rb

```
has_one :author, lambda {
    unscope(where: :active)
}
```

So basically this would work and in all context we'd return authors that are excluded by default scope

If for some reason, we need to include those excluded only in certain contexts, I may do it by introducing new

```
has_one :author_user
```

or something like this